# How to permit ospfv3 packet in ipv6 access list?

Tags: ospf, packet-tracer, access-control

In Packet Tracer, I have a private network with 5 different VLANs and inter-vlan routing enabled on R1. These are connected via an edge router to an ISP. On the interface S0/0/0 of R1 in direction in I have an ipv6 access-list defined as follows:

```
 ipv6 access-list ESTABLISHED_IPv6
 permit icmp any any echo-reply
 permit udp any host 2001:DB8:6:BC04::3 eq domain
 permit tcp any host 2001:DB8:6:BC04::4 eq 443
 permit tcp any 2001:DB8:6:BC00::/64 established
 permit tcp any 2001:DB8:6:BC01::/64 established
 permit tcp any 2001:DB8:6:BC02::/64 established
 permit tcp any 2001:DB8:6:BC03::/64 established
```

The access list allows traffic to the DMZ for DNS and https and to the VLANS If a connection has been opened from within the VLANS.

The problem is that this access-list prevents OSPFv3 packets to reach this router. How can I permit OSPFv3 packets in this access list?

[image: Setup]

Full config file of R1:

```
    Current configuration : 4811 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
!
!
enable password class
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
!
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
username Administrator password 0 Pasw0rd+
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FTX1524HE77-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.25
 encapsulation dot1Q 25
 ip address 1.0.0.4 255.255.255.248
 ip access-group DMZ out
 ipv6 address FE80::5 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC04::1/64
 ipv6 ospf 1 area 0
 standby 25 ip 1.0.0.1
 standby 25 priority 105
 standby 25 preempt
 standby 25 track Serial0/0/0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.240
 encapsulation dot1Q 240
 ip address 10.15.240.9 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.15.242.13
 ip access-group MITARBEITER in
 ipv6 traffic-filter MITARBEITER_IPv6 in
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::1 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC00::1/64
 ipv6 ospf 1 area 0
 standby 240 ip 10.15.240.1
 standby 240 priority 105
 standby 240 preempt
 standby 240 track Serial0/0/0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.241
 encapsulation dot1Q 241
 ip address 10.15.241.9 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.15.242.13
 ip access-group MGMT in
 ipv6 traffic-filter MGMT_IPv6 in
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::2 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC01::1/64
 ipv6 ospf 1 area 0
 standby 241 ip 10.15.241.1
 standby 241 priority 105
 standby 241 preempt
 standby 241 track Serial0/0/0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.242
 encapsulation dot1Q 242
 ip address 10.15.242.9 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group SERVER in
 ipv6 traffic-filter SERVER_IPv6 in
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::3 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC02::1/64
 ipv6 ospf 1 area 0
 standby 242 ip 10.15.242.1
 standby 242 priority 105
 standby 242 preempt
 standby 242 track Serial0/0/0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.243
 encapsulation dot1Q 243
 ip address 10.15.243.9 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group GAESTE in
 ipv6 traffic-filter GAESTE_IPv6 in
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::4 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC03::1/64
 ipv6 ospf 1 area 0
 standby 243 ip 10.15.243.1
 standby 243 priority 105
 standby 243 preempt
 standby 243 track Serial0/0/0
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 209.165.240.10 255.255.255.252
 ip access-group ESTABLISHED in
 ip nat outside
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC05::1/64
 ipv6 ospf 1 area 0
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ipv6 router ospf 1
 router-id 1.1.1.1
 default-information originate
 log-adjacency-changes
!
ip nat inside source list NAT interface Serial0/0/0 overload
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Serial0/0/0 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
ip access-list extended NAT
 permit ip 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.15.241.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.15.242.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.15.243.0 0.0.0.255 any
ip access-list extended SERVER
 permit ip 10.15.242.0 0.0.0.255 any
ip access-list extended MGMT
 permit udp host 0.0.0.0 eq bootpc host 255.255.255.255 eq bootps
 permit ip 10.15.241.0 0.0.0.255 any
ip access-list extended ESTABLISHED
 permit icmp any any echo-reply
 permit udp any host 1.0.0.2 eq domain
 permit tcp any host 1.0.0.3 eq 443
 permit tcp any 1.0.0.0 0.0.0.248 established
 permit tcp any 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 established
 permit tcp any 10.15.241.0 0.0.0.255 established
 permit tcp any 10.15.242.0 0.0.0.255 established
 permit tcp any 10.15.243.0 0.0.0.255 established
ip access-list extended MITARBEITER
 permit udp host 0.0.0.0 eq bootpc host 255.255.255.255 eq bootps
 deny ip 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 10.15.241.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 any
ip access-list extended GAESTE
 permit udp host 0.0.0.0 eq bootpc host 255.255.255.255 eq bootps
 deny ip 10.15.243.0 0.0.0.255 10.15.241.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip 10.15.243.0 0.0.0.255 any
ipv6 access-list MITARBEITER_IPv6
 deny ipv6 2001:DB8:6:BC00::/64 2001:DB8:6:BC01::/64
 permit ipv6 2001:DB8:6:BC00::/64 any
ipv6 access-list MGMT_IPv6
 permit ipv6 2001:DB8:6:BC01::/64 any
ipv6 access-list SERVER_IPv6
 permit ipv6 2001:DB8:6:BC02::/64 any
ipv6 access-list GAESTE_IPv6
 deny ipv6 2001:DB8:6:BC03::/64 2001:DB8:6:BC01::/64
 permit ipv6 2001:DB8:6:BC03::/64 any
ipv6 access-list ESTABLISHED_IPv6
 permit icmp any any echo-reply
 permit udp any host 2001:DB8:6:BC04::3 eq domain
 permit tcp any host 2001:DB8:6:BC04::4 eq 443
 permit tcp any 2001:DB8:6:BC00::/64
 permit tcp any 2001:DB8:6:BC01::/64
 permit tcp any 2001:DB8:6:BC02::/64
 permit tcp any 2001:DB8:6:BC03::/64
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

EDIT: Router model is 1941. Firmware is version 15.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSPF doesn't use a transport-layer protocol but rides as protocol number 89 directly on top of IP.

Depending on the router model, an inbound ACL entry looks like this:

```
permit 89 any host [router-ip]
```

or

```
permit protocol 89 any host [router-ip]
```

or

```
permit ospf any host [router-ip]
```

EDIT: permit ? does return  icmp, ipv6, tcp, udp. So it seems that OSPF is not available in packet tracer

Comment: This gives me an error hinting that 89 in invalid input

Comment: Please try `permit protocol 89 any host [router-id]` or `permit ospf any host [router-id]` or add the exact router model and firmware version to your question.

Comment: Router model is 1941. Firmware is version 15.1

Comment: Neither of these work. Either hinting on 89, protocol or ospf that  it is invalid input

Comment: What does `permit [tab]` come up with?

Comment: Tab does not return anything but ? returns: icmp, ipv6, tcp, udp

Comment: Yes, `show ?` - if there's nothing more than you can't permit any other protocol. Are you using packet tracer? That might be a limitation of the simulation, not sure about a real 1941 though.

Comment: Yes I'm using packet tracer.